# animating a wave using trigonometry in a row of objects

Tags: signal-processing, trigonometry, waveform

I have a row of objects which i want to highlight/animate as a single wave that passes by occaisionally and then all the objects go flat

______¸,ø¤º°`°º¤ø,_________ ____________________________

unfortunately i am completely failing, despite having a visual feedback of the function, it is completely out of control. please give me some suggestions. here is my failed attempt in unityscript, similar to AS:

```
function Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("b")) animating = !animating;
    if (animating ==true){
        for (movebat in movebats) //process every battery component
            { 
                var vy = movebat.transform.position.y*0.4 + Time.time*3;
                if ( vy % (Mathf.PI*4)>= (Mathf.PI)) 
                    vy = 0;
                movebat.transform.position.z  = Mathf.Sin(vy*.41+Time.time*3);
            }
    }
}
```

perhaps there is a bell curve function or an iteration trick that would be easier, and new for me?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: that's unityscript, it's similar to javascript and actionscript except it uses .net libraries and unity3d ones. thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is a version of the code that works:

```
function Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("b")) animating = !animating;
    if (animating ==true){
        for (movebat in movebats) 
            if( movebat!=null){ 
var vy = (movebat.transform.position.y*0.4+Time.time*3)% (Mathf.PI*8);
            if ( vy >= (Mathf.PI)) 
              vy = 0;
            movebat.transform.position.z  =
            -Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.Sin(vy ),0,1)*2;}
    }
}
```